# Write into a file using fstream

Tags: c++, fstream

I tried to write into a file with `fstream` using the following code. It accepts the first entry and when I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it goes into an infinite loop to the menu instead of allowing me to enter my second and third entries.

How can I fix this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;


struct Course { // structure definition

char cID[3]; 
char title[40];
int creaditHour;
};


void showChoices();

void writeCourse(fstream& file, char fileName[]);



 int main ()
 {   
 fstream database;
 char filename[]="course.dat";

 int choice;
 do
    {
    showChoices();
    cin >> choice;
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
            //  function call to write courses data
            writeCourse(database, filename);
            break;

    case 2:
            // call function 
            break;
    case 3:
            // call function 
            break;
    case 4:
            // call function 
            break;
    case 5:
            // call function 
            break;
    case 6:

        exit(1);
            break;
    default:
        cout<<"invalid input"<<endl;
    }

    }while (choice !=6);

     getchar();
     return 0;
     }


     void showChoices()
      {
      cout<< "Menu"<< endl;
      cout<< "1 : Enter Courses Data"<< endl;
      cout<< "2 : Enter ...."<< endl;
      cout<< "3 : Enter....."<< endl;
      cout<< "4 : Display ..."<< endl;
      cout<< "5 : Display Course Data"<< endl;
      cout<< "6 : Exit"<< endl;
      cout<< "Enter your choice:";
      }


     void writeCourse(fstream& aFile, char filename[])
          {
              Course courseData= {};//initialization
              aFile.open(filename,std::ios::out);
                 if (!aFile)
                  {
                   cout << "file opened for writing failed" << endl;
                   exit (-1);
                   }
              cout << endl;
              cout << "Begin Writing of " << filename << endl;
          cout << "Enter course ID, title, and creadit Hour\n? " << endl;


         for (int count=0; count<3;count++)
              {
          cin >>courseData.cID>>courseData.title>>courseData.creaditHour;
              }
         aFile.close();
         cout << "File name " << filename << " closed" << endl;
         cout << endl;
         }
```

Comment: `cin >>courseData.cID>>courseData.title>>courseData.creaditHour;` Why do you read the same three variables three times without using the first two sets of input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you input a wrong data type that you want to store. There's nothing wrong in the code.

`courseDate.creadithour` is an `int` from the `Course` struct, so when you input a `char` type,  error loop comes.

My approach for this is to change all the built in type from the `Course` struct into string and determine the input whether it is a digit or a letter.

Comment: Thanks, you are right.  I was entering the wrong data type. for courseDate.creadithour.

Comment: One question I have though,                                              
char cID[3]; 
must only take 3 input right?

Comment: It only takes one input but stores in every character

Answer (score 0):

In the function `writeCourse()`, you need to remove the for loop around the input stream so that each field will be entered exactly once for each entry. Also, you need to write the output to the file `course.dat` so that each entered record is saved in that file. Make the file open mode as "append" so that all entries will be saved. Code works as below:

```
void writeCourse(fstream& aFile, char filename[])
{
    Course courseData;//initialization
    aFile.open(filename, std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);
    if (!aFile)
    {
        cout << "file opened for writing failed" << endl;
        exit (-1);
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Begin Writing of " << filename << endl;
    cout << "Enter course ID, title, and creadit Hour\n" << endl;

    cin >> &courseData.cID[0] >> &courseData.title[0] >> courseData.creaditHour;
    aFile << &courseData.cID[0] << endl;
    aFile << &courseData.title[0] << endl;
    aFile << courseData.creaditHour << endl;
    aFile.close();
    cout << "File name " << filename << " closed" << endl;
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: you are correct, I should write the input into "aFile" so that it will save it to "course.dat", Thank you for the help.